# Is it possible to deploy an AWS ECS service to a EC2 scaling group or 1 particular EC2 instance without using either of load balancer or target group

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cloudformation, amazon-ecs

Is it possible to deploy an AWS ECS service to an EC2 scaling group or 1 particular EC2 instance without using either of load balancer or target group through Cloudformation? If so, how should such an ECS service be coded in Cloudfromation?

Comment: Yes, it is. Have you attempted the template?

Comment: @GeorgeRushby Which template are you referring to? I have seen several template examples provided by AWS, but they all seem to have a load balancer and target group in them...

Comment: @GeorgeRushby I would be very helpful if you could link such a template.

Comment: The Loadbalancer is NOT required so just omit it from the template  https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-ecs-service.html#cfn-ecs-service-loadbalancers

Comment: @GeorgeRushby Ok, I'll try by simply omitting it.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know.